# Error : FragmentActivity whem I want to create swipe

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

When I want to create a swipe tab **PagerView** in my application. But the error see it:
**LogCat**

```
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847): java.lang.StackOverflowError
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.widget.TextView.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(TextView.java:4518)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
09-23 13:15:00.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):     at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5147)
```

I have more four FragmentTabOne, FragmentTabTwo.... FragmentTabFour

Code **FragmentTabOne.java**:

```
public class FragmentTabOne extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttabone, container);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Here my layout file see :
**fragmenttabone.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Fragment 1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**mainlayout.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

I have these fragments and layout how to solve it. Fix my Error.

Help me..

Comment: If you run with 3 tabs, this exception occur or not?

Comment: @Mr. Neo Yes .When 2 tab or more than exception occur

Comment: In `mainlayout.xml`, I think you should have `LinearLayout` or `RelaytiveLayout` is parent of `ViewPager`. I am developing using `PagerView`, everything look like yours but `mainlayout.xml` is different and I don't get this error.

Comment: But how can i fix it

Comment: @Mr. Neo I check LinearLayout in layout file same error

Comment: Could you post your `Mainactivity.java` and `PagerAdapter` code

Comment: **Code** public class PagerMain extends FragmentActivity {

 ViewPager viewPager;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.pager_main);

  viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
  viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

 }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90408/discussion-between-raaz-and-mr-neo).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know this could help you. You could give it a try.
But this is my `mainlayout.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStripV22
            android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#FF6600"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/ViewPagerStripStyle"/>

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this  xml error android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStripV22

Comment: in your case, use `android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip` instead of `android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStripV22`

Comment: Errror Mr. neo 09-23 15:06:13.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2760): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStripV22
09-23 15:06:13.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2760):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
09-23 15:06:13.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2760):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-23 15:06:13.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2760):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)

Comment: Please change to `android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip`. In my case, I have to use `PagerTabStripV22`, a modified version of `PagerTabStrip`

Answer (score 0):

such

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttabone, null);
```